# Telegram channels can pump a coin by 50%-200%

Tags: altcoin, investing

I ran into couple of this channels on Telegram (it's an encrypted messaging software like whatsapp) 
I joined a couple of them after a friend advised me and said there are channel who are giving signals on specific coins, and making them jump by hundreds of percentage in a few minutes, 
how is this possible? If it's that easy to make profits on those altcoins why doesn't everybody doing it?
Just as an exemple, one of them is t.me/whaletank and http://affiliateceo.blogspot.com/ , most promising so far.
Can someone recommend me on few others to check out? I don't even know where i can search for more of this kind of groups, but I'm sure there are more..
I would like to join any kind of a large group with 1000+ people on it, I find it the best way to make profits right now when the whole market just keep crashing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  
both recommendations and investment advice are off-topic here.

Answer (score 4):

Most of these so called pump and dump groups are illegitimate or downright scams.

They usually only work for the inner group and the promoters who want to get you to join.

The scam works by buying the coin a few days earlier and then announce that you should buy the coin at a later time...the people like you try to buy the coins and then the promoters dump the coins at the high prices. By the time you buy it is too late unless you can sell instantly.

You have to think, if this was a real way of doing things then everyone would do this!